# Handling auto-assign of project and members role for LDAP Users in Report Portal

Tags: ldap, testng, reportportal

I want to auto-assign a few of the Projects to the user who is logging in using the LDAP credentials. Currently, if LDAP user logs in, I have to go in Report Portal using super admin credentials and assign Member Role and Projects to that specific member.

I have recently tried this LDAP feature and facing this issue of the new user gets creating and assigning projects and members to each one of them. I wan some auto-assignment (like can we passed while setting LDAP setting in Report Portal)

Below is my LDAP user **nperiwal** with which I logged in Report Portal. But as you see this got created a new user and no project got assigned to it automatically. I want some process or code or settings which can fulfil my requirement.
[image]

FYI, see the below snapshot where I manually assigned projects and admin role.
[image]

Please help.

Comment: @[dzmitry-humianiuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7166826/dzmitry-humianiuk) - Please take a look and help. I am stuck here.

Comment: Simillar issue has been raised in Report Portal GitHub [here](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/615?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way:**
 It can be done via scripting, see which requests are send to server in browser Network tab and put the same into the bash/shell script. Parametrize according to username and required access.

**Long way:** wait until our team will implement it within ReportPortal as feature, based on regular priority

**Best way:** request payed support from our team, and we will implement this capabilities for your company with highest priority. Drop mail at `support@reportportal.io`